# How to use BBcode syntax highlighting in Sublime Text

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, bbcode

I have searched through the Sublime Text packages and can't seem to find a BBCode syntax highlighting package. I tried a couple for BBcode syntax which work great, but they don't use syntax highlighting.

I currently use IPS BBCode and Color Highlighting, but would really like to have the `[code] [color]` etc. in a highlighted syntax.

Comment: Are you only interested in getting a pre-prepared package or do you have any interest in writing your own syntax highlighting? I don't want to suggest the later if it would offend. I have written a couple for obscure languages that are too messy to publish but do what I need to get syntax highlighting that works for me and happy to talk you through the steps to get started if you are interested.

Comment: I decided to go on a learning curve and started making my own BBCode Syntax with Highlighting. I am very pleased with it so far, just need to add the Regex with certain things for aesthetic purposes. (http://regexr.com/38va5) I should have it on the hub in a week or so.  ^_^

Comment: Hi Tac, did you ever release this? I'm looking for a simple BBCode syntax highlighting plugin for Sublime at the minute but not having much luck finding one so far :(